# Sharing function that takes input variables between installer and uninstaller

Tags: nsis

How can I modifiy the below syntax such that my library function can be used in both the installer and the uninstaller? So far I have only managed to find an example for functions that do not take an input value. A good example of which can be found here:

http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Sharing_functions_between_Installer_and_Uninstaller

I haven't been able to work out the syntax should you want to pass varaibles and still utilise the function for both installer and uninstaller.

```
/* FILE: MyFunctionLibrary.nsh */

Function MyFunction
  !define MyFunction"!insertmacro MyFunctionCall"

  !macro MyFunctionCall _VAR1
    Push "${_VAR1}"
    Call MyFunction
  !macroend

  Exch $0
  MessageBox MB_OK $0
  Pop $0

FunctionEnd

/* FILE: MyInstallerScript.nsi */

/*...mui setup stuff...*/

!include "MyFunctionLibrary.nsh"

Section Install SEC01

  ${MyFunction} "install section"

SectionEnd

Section UnInstall SEC02

  ${MyFunction} "uninstall section"

SectionEnd

/*...other stuff...*/
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things going on here. You need to generate both functions and that is often done with a macro. You can also (optionally) provide a helper macro you use to call the function.

The most important step is creating the functions:

```
; --- MyFunctionLibrary.nsh ---
!macro DeclareMyFunction un
Function ${un}MyFunction
Exch $0
DetailPrint "MyFunction: parameter=$0"
Pop $0
FunctionEnd
!macroend

; --- MyInstallerScript.nsi ---
!insertmacro DeclareMyFunction ""
Section
Push "Hello World"
Call MyFunction
SectionEnd

!insertmacro DeclareMyFunction "un."
Section Uninstall
Push "Hello World"
Call un.MyFunction
SectionEnd
```

There is also a less common way you can use by providing just the functions code in the macro:

```
!macro MyFunctionCode
Exch $0
DetailPrint "MyFunction: parameter=$0"
Pop $0
!macroend

Function MyFunction
!insertmacro MyFunctionCode
FunctionEnd
Function un.MyFunction
!insertmacro MyFunctionCode
FunctionEnd
```

The macro that helps you call the function just needs to perform x number of `Push`'s and `Call` YourFunction or un.YourFunction:

```
!macro DeclareMyFunction un
Function ${un}MyFunction
Exch $0
DetailPrint "MyFunction: parameter=$0"
Pop $0
FunctionEnd
!macroend

!define MyFunction "!insertmacro CallMyFunction"
!macro CallMyFunction Param1
Push "${Param1}"
!ifdef __UNINSTALL__
Call un.MyFunction
!else
Call MyFunction
!endif
!macroend

!insertmacro DeclareMyFunction ""
Section
${MyFunction} "Hello World"
SectionEnd

!insertmacro DeclareMyFunction "un."
Section Uninstall
${MyFunction} "Hello World"
SectionEnd
```

Some of the details can be abstracted away by using util.nsh:

```
!include Util.nsh

!macro MyFunction
Exch $0
DetailPrint "MyFunction: parameter=$0"
Pop $0
!macroend

!define MyFunction "!insertmacro CallMyFunction"
!macro CallMyFunction Param1
Push "${Param1}"
!insertmacro CallArtificialFunction MyFunction
!macroend

Section
${MyFunction} "Hello World"
SectionEnd

Section Uninstall
${MyFunction} "Hello World"
SectionEnd
```